# Svg logo does not resize

Tags: html, svg

I have a problem with a SVG file that doesn't resize no matter what I try to change. I would like to make the image a bit larger, but nothing happens if I change the viewBox or the width/height. My source code:

```
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
            <a href="index.html" class="logo">
                <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 1000 800" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 800" xml:space="preserveAspectRatio="X800Y800 meet">
    <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA+gAAAMgCAYAAACwGEg9AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJ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=">
</image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Add width="100%" height="100%" to the <svg> element perhaps.

Comment: `xml:space="preserveAspectRatio="X800Y800 meet"` is an error, `xlink:href="data:image/png;base64, the svg file itself` is a joke

Comment: You appear to be missing the code for your SVG. Difficult to help with that missing.

Comment: Added the Svg code as well

Comment: why do you base64-embed an image within an SVG document and not just use the image directly via `img` tag?

Answer (score 0):

It's resizing just fine for me.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 1000 800">
    <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA+gAAAMgCAYAAACwGEg9AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJ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=">
</image>
</svg>
```